# Split file name by character

Tags: python

I would like to split a file name using a specific character within the file name. For instance:

```
FileName = MyFile_1.1_A.txt
(File, ext) = os.path.splitext(FileName)
print File
```

This will give an output of:

```
MyFile_1.1_A
```

However, I would like to get an output of:

```
MyFile_1.1
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What if the filename is `MyFile_1.1_A.2_B.txt`? Would you expect `MyFile_1.1_A.2`, `MyFile_1.1`, or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the file format is standard, you can use [`rsplit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit)

```
print FileName.rsplit('_', 1)[0]
```

Answer (score 5):

Another variation

```
FileName.rpartition('_')[0]
```

Comment: This is the best answer IMHO. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> fn='MyFile_1.1_A.txt'
>>> re.split(r'_[^_]*$',fn)
['MyFile_1.1', '']
>>> fn='file_name_with_many_under_scores_1.1_.txt'
>>> re.split(r'_[^_]*$',fn)
['file_name_with_many_under_scores_1.1', '']
```

Answer (score 1):

how about:

```
FileName = 'MyFile_1.1_A.txt'
File = '_'.join(FileName.rsplit('_')[:-1])
print File
```

For example, this also handles another case:

```
In [1]: FileName = 'MyFile_ohyeah_1.1_A.txt'

In [2]: File = '_'.join(FileName.rsplit('_')[:-1])

In [3]: File
Out[3]: 'MyFile_ohyeah_1.1'
```

Comment: you can use a limit on number of splits for rsplit. why go through the trouble of joining again ?

Comment: @karthikr, I didn't know that.  Your answer is superior.

Comment: its not superior. its just awareness :) you were almost there.